# ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4) but there is four

Tags: python-3.x, valueerror

Before I start I wanna say I'm new to coding so if my question has a simple answer that I can't see, well, you know why. Anyway, here's the part that is giving the error:

```
class_, weapon, rogue_wep, race = class_selection(class_, weapon, rogue_wep, race)

print(class_ + weapon + rogue_wep + race)
```

Now when this value error was explained to me I understood it as when you have more variables on one side then the other, for example:

```
a, b, c, = example_func(a, b, c, d)
```

This would be an error because there are too many variables on the right side packing into the left side. Well in my case four variables are being packed into four variables. (Something to note: `class_` is already defined as the thing it's going to be set as, but in my testing this doesn't give this error.)

Whole game's code: https://pastebin.com/uUVwwJBb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function class_selection return only one variable: __class
so there are you should do:

```
class_ = class_selection(class_, weapon, rogue_wep, race) print(class_ + weapon + rogue_wep + race)
print(class_ + weapon + rogue_wep + race)
```

if you want the 4 values class_selection should return the them:

```
return class_, weapon, rogue_wep, race
```

edit:
after reading your code I think you need to read about global variables in python. what happens is that values assigned inside the functions are not assigned to the global variables you defiend. for this you need to do:

```
global x
x = "some value"
```

Comment: thanks, but the other values are assigned in other functions so when i return them in class_selection they come up as their default blank

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, if you want the values from the outside from the function , why aren't you just using them?

Comment: All the variables are defined in functions, so to make them defined outside of the functions I am returning them. Without doing that they are set to their default value which I set as ' '. Is this what you mean?

Comment: in python unless you specify variable as global it is a variable assignment is local to the function.

Comment: oh you can make variables global, see this is the stuff that will probably make it work that i didn't know about, thanks.